Did my decision to decline a full time lecturer position look bad at all?
I'm in my 5th year in my PhD program in Experimental Psychology.
I declined a position for a full-time lecturer position back in June. I made this decision in large part due to my low ratings as a visiting full-time instructor at a small liberal arts college, as well as major issues I had related to autistic burnout and other behavioral issues that warranted me going on ketamine throughout October.
Notably, I asked this campus to extend my decision date by a week. I didn't email them until an hour or two after the decision deadline to decline the offer. They never replied to that email or anything. However, I did see they reposted the job listing a week or so after I declined it.
Even though my decision was a while ago, it came up recently in discussions I had with other disabled academics (I'm autistic, have ADHD-inattentive, dysgraphia, and 3rd-percentile processing speed). Some people in those discussion said the decision I made was "stupid," among other comments.
Does this mean my name will be "blacklisted" as someone not to hire for other instructor positions in the future? If so, this doesn't really matter since I hated teaching by the end of everything with a passion. This campus was a regional campus of a flagship university, did I burn a bridge with the flagship?
Does rejecting this position look bad? I'm primarily concerned about how this will affect my already negative reputation in my own department. Would people writing me letters of recommendation maybe note I set myself back on opportunities?

Out of curiosity, what does your Plan B currently look like?

@Aruralreader I never had a Plan B after I rejected the position since I'm still working on my dissertation (albeit data's collected so it's the Results and Discussion sections at this point) and have a fellowship where I need to attend four in person events this academic year to stay active. The fellowship awarded me $11k last year, which I haven't touched yet. I need to attend those events to stay active in the system and keep the money.

Is this a position you applied for or one offered to you? "Lecturer" means different things in different countries. Is the UK or elsewhere?

@Buffy This is in the US. I applied to it, got an offer, then rejected it.

@Aruralreader I nearly forgot to mention this as well, but I have multiple disabilities and am in the Federal Workforce Recruitment program as well as my home state's vocational rehabilitation to help me find a job that can accommodate me. Teaching was a bust sadly.

What are your plans after your PhD? What type of work do you envision doing after that?

What sort of advice has your advisor given you?

@Aruralreader I've asked for advice on career searching and he honestly hasn't given me anything as far as that goes. I even asked what he thinks would be a fit for me and he said that it was up for me to decide. My first PhD advisor (before she dropped me) suggested academia was the path for me since my social skills weren't good enough for industry (yes, really). Even though things ended poorly between me and my first advisor, she was the only one who gave a clear goal that she thought was reasonable and was why I tried an adjunct then visiting full time instructor role. It's up in the air.

@Polygnome I always wanted to work as a full time research assistant in some capacity. However, I was told I'd be overqualified for such positions. I do want to get one of the social science research analyst/specialist positions in my state though. ETA: I should note that I successfully passed a competency test for one of these positions, ended up being 1/3 interviewees, and then got rejected sadly.

As a side note, the best strategy is not to apply for positions you know you would reject even if they were offered to you and you had no other offers. (It's true that our knowledge of which positions these are can change over time.)

@GregMartin The time I applied was back in October to Novmeber 2023 though. This was before I got completely jaded by teaching and had an official job offer in hand around June-July 2024. I also reused a lot of the application materials I had for the visiting instructor position as well so my effort at that point was minimal. My fellowship also has service requirements for me to keep the money I was awarded and could've potentially got more had I graduated before the position started (this didn't happen) in this case. I'm glad I did it anyway since they reimbursed my travel expenses.

"However, I did see they reposted the job listing a week or so after I declined it." Well, yeah? I'm not sure why you mention this. Also, what would you like to do with the answer to this question?

@AzorAhai-him- I only bring up that the job got relisted since my competition for it either wasn't high or no one accepted at all. As for what I'd like to do with the answer to the question, I'd say it's completely fine so feel free to close the question or do whatever you all need to do when a satisfactory answer is given.

@zzmondo1 No, we don’t close questions when they get answers. What I mean is, there’s not much you can do with the answer to this question, so why are you asking? To guide answers.

@AzorAhai-him- I'm asking because I've had mixed responses to my decision to decline the position. Some have even gone as far as to say I've burned a bigger bridge than I thought because the university I rejected is a regional campus of a flagship university in that state. I'm not good with sussing out information in these situations, hence why I deferred to this forum.

You said you weren't worried about burning a bridge though, because you are no longer interested in teaching?

I reflowed your question a little based on your comments. You kind of jumped back and forth between what happened and why you're asking. Please do edit if I made a mistake.

A lot of people decline a lot of positions for a lot of reasons. I don't know of such things as "blacklists" in the US, though people in a given field know one another to some extent and may talk. But, declining in order to have time to finish your research is valid.
I seriously doubt that declining the offer will add to your difficulties.
In any case, it is what it is, and you will need to address the issue if and when it arises, perhaps in a question during an interview. But even that seems doubtful to me.
Good luck finding the right fit.

It is worth clarifying that I declined because I would have some in person duties with all online courses. Given my major mental health issues (and physical, albeit to a lesser extent), I wanted to be around my support system again and not have to worry about living while I was at it too. I'm living with my parents right now.
